# How to sync two process (child and parent) with signals in C?

Tags: c, process, signals

I want use signal (SIGUSR1) to sync process in C. I want that parent process wainting for a signal, when receive this signal, send the same signal to child process. I wrote a short paragraph to stimulate reasoning, but it does not go away.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>



void trataSIGUSR1(int sigNum) {
    printf("SIGUSR1\n");
}

int main(void) {

    pid_t pid;
    struct sigaction sa;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        struct sigaction sa = {0};
        sa.sa_handler = trataSIGUSR1;
        sa.sa_flags = 0;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sa,NULL);
        pause();
        printf("This never execute");
    } else {
        printf("I'am father: %d!\n",getppid());
        kill(0,SIGUSR1);
        pause();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I'am father: 12082!
User defined signal 1: 30
```

Comment: Maybe try to wait for a signal in the parent and try to send a signal to the parent.

Comment: how I do this? I don't know how to wait a signal, I don't want use busy waiting.

Comment: [`pause()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) [`kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)

Comment: do you can show to me how to use this? I can set a especific signal to continue code after `pause()`?

Comment: Try `sigaction() - examine and change a signal action`. For more detail, just type `man sigaction`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple hint is use `pause()` and `kill()` i.e `pause()` is for block the process execution until any signal received, once signal received then `do_something()` and `kill()` is for sending the `SIGUSR1` signal.

Also when you use `pause()`, it will suspend the process until it received any signal and for that signal default action should be user defined ISR. from manual page of `pause()`

> RETURN VALUE
>          `pause()` returns only when a `signal was caught` and the  `signal-catching  function`  returned.
>          In this case pause() returns -1, and errno is set to EINTR.

Here is the sample required example code

```
//int nSIGINT = 0; /* declare variable of type volatile sigatomic_t  */
volatile sigatomic_t nSIGINT;
void trataSIGINT(int sigNum) {
    nSIGINT = 1;/* set the flag as needed */
}
int main(void ){
        int pid;
        pid=fork();/* create child process */
        if(pid==0) {    
                //signal(SIGUSR1,trataSIGINT);/* instead of signal() use sigaction  */
                struct sigaction sa = {0}; /* initialize sa or fill all its members*/
                sa.sa_handler = trataSIGINT;/* set the handler to trataSIGINT*/
                sa.sa_flags = 0;
                sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
                sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sa,NULL); /* when child received SIGUSR1, trataSIGINT gets called */
                pause(); /* wait until any signal received */
                /* do_something_child() code, this you want to run only after receiving signal */

        }
        else { 
                /* do_something_parent() */
                printf("parent about to send user signal to child\n");
                kill(pid,SIGUSR1); /*send SIGUSR1 to child */
                wait(0); /* wait till child completes  */
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Side note, for setting a flag in `trataSIGINT()` when `SIGUSR1` received, instead of declaring `int nSIGINT = 0;` declare flag variable as type of `volatile sigatomic_t` type.

> **From ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.14.1.1 The `signal` function**
>
> ¶5 If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or
>   `raise` function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler
>   refers to any object with `static` or thread storage duration that is
>   not a `lock-free atomic object` other than by assigning a value to an
>   object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or the signal handler
>   calls any function in the standard library other than the `abort`
>   function, the `_Exit` function, the `quick_exit` function, or the
>   signal function with the first argument equal to the signal number
>   corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler.
>   Furthermore, if such a call to the signal function results in a
>   `SIG_ERR` return, the value of `errno` is indeterminate.252)
>
> 252) If any signal is generated by an asynchronous signal handler, the
>   behavior is `undefined`.

Comment: Note that pause() returns i any signal is received. You might want to put that in a loop that checks a `volatile int usr1_received;` and set that to true in the signal handler for SIGUSR1. And avoid any library that already uses SIGUSR1 itself. Better to use posix mutexes and conditions.

Comment: yes true @GoswinvonBrederlow or `volatile sigatomic_t usr1_received;` would be better as `sigatomic_t`  type is always accessed atomically and  avoid uncertainty about interrupting access to a variable.

Comment: Not works.. when I execute the codes automatically finished.

Comment: The func `trataSIGINT` never run, and the code below `pause()` of child process also not execute.

Comment: You should show the code then only I can tell about _Not works..?_ check whether parent sending signal or not.

Comment: What is `kill(0,SIGUSR1);` ? It should be `kill(pid,SIGUSR1);`

Comment: Also why `pause()` in parent process? Remove it, one after `kill`.

Comment: please mention the reason for down voting.